Unity Rigidbody2D AddForce not consistent
I am applying force to a rigidbody using
ammo.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0, -250f));

But this force is not always consistent. Sometimes 'ammo' moves slower than at other times.
I am calling AddForce inside Update() function. I tried replacing it with FixedUpdate() but no difference. What am i missing?

well, it should be fixed update, but, what variances are you seeing?

ammo.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0, -250f), ForceMode2D.Impulse);

